# Take my Google Maps timeline data as input, and output a map showing where I've been + all the paths I've taken

Tags: maps, google-maps, travel

I'm looking for a program or web service that can take my Google Maps timeline data as input, and output a map showing where I've been + all the paths I've taken.

Any license, OS or price is fine.

E.g.,:

[image]

In GMaps, I don't see a way to generate a map showing all the paths I've taken in all my life as a GMaps user: I only see maps for a given day, and not all time.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pGYTyy)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/nt5jog)

Answer (score 2):

You can export entire Location history via [Google takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) (select KML as output format). Next I will recommend to convert KML to GPX the location file (I use [GPSBabel](https://www.gpsbabel.org/)). Then you can use [GPX Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gpxeditor/) and get something like as result (tested with 36MB GPX, >200k points)
[image: GPX Editor OpenStreetMap]

P.S. No affiliation with any of the companies/vendors/developers